# UITableViewCell resizing won't affect touch area

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, autoresize

I have UITableView where cells are taken from UITableViewCell created with Interface Builder (xib) file.

The problem is the touch area of the cell is unaffected regardless of the cell's frame. Is there a way to fix this ?

- xib view size is 768x60 (because need to support portrait as well)
- The content is resized without a problem but the touch area remains unchanged. My original cell size from IB is 768x60 where new size is 1024x60 (landscape).
- The cell however is not getting selected if touch X point is between 768-1024 )
- IB's structs are set to the following (check image), i also tried few different settings as well.

  [image]

How do I fix this ? Here is a log from layoutSubviews method inside UITableViewCell class.

**Code**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    NSLog(@"pre frame > %@ ",NSStringFromCGRect(self.contentView.frame));
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"post frame > %@ ",NSStringFromCGRect(self.contentView.frame));
}
```

**Output**

```
pre frame > {{0, 0}, {748, 62}} // before calling [super layoutSubviews]
post frame > {{0, 0}, {1004, 62}} // after calling [super layoutSubviews]
```

*** * Update *** *

I could not figure out patching this code up due to deadlines & hence I re created the xib file from scratch (For the big container view that included UITableView not the UITableViewCell) and the problem seemed to have gone away. Thanks everyone who tried to help.

Comment: is UITableView can change frame ?

Comment: Check User Interaction enabled for `UITableView` & `Cell` in XIB

Comment: One of your tablecell's superview surely shorter in frame than your tablecell's frame (in  landscape mode). That's why touch area is not working. You need to properly check all superview's frame by putting either background colors or logs watever way you like.

Comment: NANNAV - Yes it can change frame   
Navnath - Yes I even enabled it in code just to make sure
@Divyu - How do you propose I do that ? I'll loop through the views in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?   
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all super views (from tableview to self.window.rootViewController in app delegate)  changed frame size to landscape too.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the problem here. I found that 2 layers (between UITableview & window) have a frame of {0 0 ; 768 1024} which surprised me. Its basically the first screen after launch, very confused on this as it never happened to me before :(